# Read excel content after get data from particular cell

Tags: apache-poi, katalon-studio

I have existing codes that work to get a particular cell from an excel sheet.
is that possible to read particular content within the cell?

**excel reader:**

```html
public String ReadCellData(int vRow, int vColumn)
 {
  String value=null;          //variable for storing the cell value
  Workbook wb=null;           //initialize Workbook null
  try
  {
   //reading data from a file in the form of bytes
      FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + "/Data Files/testmatrix.xlsx");
   //constructs an XSSFWorkbook object, by buffering the whole stream into the memory
   wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch(IOException e1)
  {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
  Sheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);   //getting the XSSFSheet object at given index
  Row row=sheet.getRow(vRow); //returns the logical row
  Cell cell=row.getCell(vColumn); //getting the cell representing the given column
  //value=cell.getStringCellValue();    //getting cell value
  //return value;               //returns the cell value
 }
}
```

**codes to get and print data**

```html
//read excel cell C11, ignore first row column A1. (int vRow, int vColumn)
def exceldata = CustomKeywords.'test.readexcel.ReadCellData'(11, 2)

String jsondata = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(exceldata.toString())

println(jsondata)

WebUI.delay(1)

//call the object and post the above data as API HTTP request body
def post = ((findTestObject('Object Repository/Web Service Request/test-service/Post')) as RequestObject)

post.setBodyContent(new HttpTextBodyContent(jsondata))

WebUI.delay(2)

//POST and verification
def response = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(post)

println(response.statusCode)

assert response.getStatusCode() == 201
```

**excel data at Cell C11**

I want to get the value of key testId.

```html
{
  "testId": "test123",
  "created": "2020-02-06T17:02:39.257Z",
}
```

Comment: See https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents.

Comment: @AxelRichter is my exieing codes (comment out) , value=cell.getStringCellValue();    //getting cell value , the one i can make use to get cell value? but i need specific content only, not whole cell.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the response:

```
def parsedResponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.getResponseText())
println parsedResponse.get("testId")
```

(don't forget to `import groovy.json.JsonSlurper`)

Comment: hmm nope, i guess you misunderstand what i needed. my code already has 'println(jsondata)' , what i mean is how do I bind it as part of the def response = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(post) ? a new syntax/parameter? i am not sure. i know how to get response but how to bind it?